# Javascript: Too many nested promises

Tags: javascript, angular, promise

I'm using Angular `HttpClient` to store some data in a server, but I'm stuck with one repeated instruction. The saving process will be as follow:

```
if(client is new){
  //promise starts
  store client and retrieve id


  if(client has companion){
    //promise starts
    store companion and retrieve id

    //promise starts
    store product with previous retrieved id
  }
  //promise starts
  store product with only client id

}else{
  //promise starts
  store product 
}
```

As you can see the 'store product' instruction is repeated three times due to the fact that I need information back from the server before moving on. 
Here is the actual code:

```
//Check if the client is new
    if (this.rent.client.id === 0) {

      this.clientServce.saveClientToDatabase(this.rent.client)
        .subscribe((results) => {
          //Store the new client Id
          this.rent.client.id = results.clientID;

          //Check if companion exists and save it to database
          if (this.rent.companion.id !== -1) {
            this.clientServce.saveCompanionToDatabase(this.rent.companion)
              .subscribe((companionResults) => {
                this.rent.companion.id = companionResults.clientID;

                //Save te rent
                this.rentServices.saveRentToDatabase(this.rent).subscribe()
              })
          } else {
            //Save te rent
            this.rentServices.saveRentToDatabase(this.rent).subscribe();
          }
        })
    } else {
      //Save te rent
      this.rentServices.saveRentToDatabase(this.rent).subscribe();

    }
```

It does look readable. So how can is possible to manage the client and companion storing and store the product at last in an readable way?

Comment: Maybe  destructure `this` so that the property names get shorter

Comment: 1. Those aren't promises; you're subscribing, they're observables. 2. Look into the operators that observables have, you could flatten this out with some maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested subscribe blocks are an anti patterns. As is your code is susceptible to multiple race conditions. You are manipulating the internal service state between http calls. Which means that if there are multiple calls fired to the `saveClientToDatabase` in a quick succession, some of them could potentially end up with incorrect data.

Try something like this instead:

```
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs/observable/forkJoin';

const hasCompanion = this.rent.companion.id !== -1;
const rent = this.rent;

const saveClient$ = this.clientService.saveClientToDatabase(rent.client);
const saveCompanion$ = hasCompanion ? this.clientService.saveCompanionToDatabase(rent.companion) : of(null);

const saveRent$ = forkJoin([saveClient$, saveCompanion$]).pipe(mergeMap(([client, companion]: [any, any]) => {
  return this.rentServices.saveRentToDatabase(companion ? {
     ...rent,
     clientID: client.clientID,
     companion: companion.companionID
   } : {
     ...rent,
     clientID: client.clientID,
   })
}));

// single subscription and single manipulation of the internal state
saveRent$.subscribe(rent => this.rent = rent);
```